# Read Extension of file in resources

Tags: vb.net, resources, embedded-resource, .net-assembly

How can I write a code to read the **extension** of a `My.Resources` file?

**Example:**

if i have a file named `IMG.JPEG` in my resources

How can I make msgbox to show the extension `.JPEG` ?

I can show the file name but without extension with this

```
For Each Fe In My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet _
(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, False, True)
        MsgBox(Fe.Key)
Next
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**

I can get the extension of file but as `.BYTE[]` and pictures as `.Bitmap` with this code

```
GT = Path.GetExtension(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(Fe.Key).ToString)
MsgBox(GT)
```

How can i get the original extension?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the filename you just need:

```
sExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sFileName)
```

Or:

```
sExt = sFileName.SubString(sFileName.LastIndexOf("."c))
```

Comment: it work only with the files that's not in resources ,  how can i get the extension of file in resources ?